# how to read string from xml response body in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xml-parsing, dynatrace

i am trying to read the token value from xml response body in javascript variable
so far i tried

```html
if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
api.fail("HTTP error: " + response.getStatusCode()); }
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('string');
```

[xml response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJJM.png)

ENTC~OTKtfKDRu7DIOj0buMfv+PdYDC62yS5GdRHeMO8H+/9UaUs8b2rpN67ONWO3XMkI96zV7x3jVQbeJNovp9Mhh4FbqXsqH2YB/MO/i8y7gJp2GG0QxczIC2oSosSSCAWK

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error? From the code you posted you are never declaring xmlDoc. Maybe var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('string'); should be var x = xmlresponseBody.getElementsByTagName('string');?

Comment: changed from xmlresponse to xmlDoc

Answer (score 1):

To read in JS, you need to use `DOMParser` API. Following is an example:

```js
const text = "<string>This is my xml</string>"; //API response in XML
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
const value = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(value)
```

Edit: Example using `fetch()` API

```
fetch('Your_API_URL')
.then(response=>response.text())
.then(data=>{
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
    const value = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(value)
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: how do i read xml response in code, i want read first node value

Comment: I suppose you are already reading in your code. 

var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;; //same as 'text' variable in code above.

Comment: i am making a Http GET request which is giving me a xml response

Comment: Once you get the response from your HTTP GET. Post successful callback/promise/async-await, string can be extracted from the response.

Comment: can you help me with that @Pramod Mali?

Comment: i want read the response and extract the token string and store it in a variable to later use

Comment: @NikhilPatil, I have updated my answer with example showing how to call API and use its XML response.