# Cypress parse XML response

Tags: javascript, xml, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have an api, which return xml data.

I am writing a testcase in cypress, through which I am requesting that api, which returns following data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Student>
    <Roll>55</Roll>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
</Student>
```

How do I parse this response body and get `Name` of the student from this response ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synchronously, with jQuery

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Student>
    <Roll>55</Roll>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
  </Student>`

it('parses the student name from xml', () => {

  function xmlProperty(xml, property) {
    return Cypress.$(Cypress.$.parseXML(xml)).find(property).text()
  }

  const name = xmlProperty(xml, 'Name') 
  console.log(name)

})
```

or in a Cypress command chain

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Student>
    <Roll>55</Roll>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
  </Student>`

it('parses student name in a Cypress command', () => {

  cy.wrap(Cypress.$(xml))
    .then(xml => xml.filter('student').find('name').text())
    .should('eq', 'ABC')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Edi: I made a search and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496907/how-to-read-string-from-xml-response-body-in-javascript) that has good solutions that seems to be working

```
 const text = "<string>This is my xml</string>"; //API response in XML
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
const value = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(value)
```

Comment: JSON.parse() for XML data?

Comment: I edited my response pls check the new version